# SQL Server Grouping On Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server

After narrowing down a large dataset I have the output of a table below. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
ID      RID Date        Time
1001    1   02/05/2009  12:24:01
1001    2   02/05/2009  13:54:01
1002    3   14/04/2012  10:36:01
1002    4   21/03/2014  11:46:01
1002    5   21/03/2014  14:40:01
```

How can I group the dates together only if they are the same and then have a table with all the times listed (output 1) or alternatively just have the dates and the DATEDIFF of the times (output 2).

All I can think of is using a CURSOR but I am trying to avoid that.

Output 1

```
ID      Date        Time 1      Time 2
1001    02/05/2009  12:24:01    13:54:01
1002    21/03/2014  11:46:01    14:40:01
```

Output 2

```
ID      Date        Time Diff
1001    02/05/2009  01:04:00
1002    21/03/2014  03:02:00
```

Comment: What is the maximum number of times per row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple grouping:

```
Select ID, Date, Min(Time) As Time1, Max(Time) As Time2
From TableName
Group By ID, Date

Select ID, Date, Datediff(ss, Min(Time), Max(Time)) As Seconds,
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(Datediff(ss, Min(Time), Max(Time)) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST((Datediff(ss, Min(Time), Max(Time)) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(Datediff(ss, Min(Time), Max(Time)) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) As Time
From TableName
Group By ID, Date
```

Comment: Nice one, I didn't think of min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work nicely:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    rid INT NOT NULL,
    dt DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.test1
        ( id, rid, dt )
VALUES  
( 1001, 1, '02/may/2009 12:24:01'),
( 1001, 2, '02/may/2009 13:54:01'),
( 1002, 3, '14/apr/2012 10:36:01'),
( 1002, 4, '21/mar/2014 11:46:01'),
( 1002, 5, '21/mar/2014 14:40:01')

SELECT id, CAST(dt AS DATE), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(dt), MIN(dt))
FROM dbo.test1
GROUP BY id, CAST(dt AS DATE)
```